# [iOS][Xamarin.UITests] : Xamarin.UITests can not detect real iPhone over Wifi

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.uitest, uitest

I'm running an iOS test written by Xamarin.UITests project into a real iPhone device over the same Wifi network, but when I run the testcase, Visual Studio for Mac does not seem to detect my iPhone.

It shows the following error:

> **System.Exception : Unable to determine simulator version for 494fcf8e0560bb352db55719359a69ec32b2430d**

Here is my environment:

- MacOS: 10.15.7 - Catalina
- iPhone: 7 Plus - iOS: 13.7

Is there anyone able to help me with this issue?

Many thanks,

Comment: Check your XCode version. This link below. would be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567333/ui-test-not-able-to-run-ios-ui-tests-unable-to-determine-simulator-version-fo

Comment: Many thanks for your advise.